# ErrorException Object of class Laravel\Socialite\Two\User could not be converted to string

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.5, laravel-socialite

I am trying to implement socialite in laravel

When the redirect happens from google and `$user = Socialite::driver('google')->stateless()->user();` instruction is called i get this error

```
ErrorException Object of class Laravel\Socialite\Two\User could not be converted to string
```

any help appreciated.

here is my code

```
public function redirectToProvider()
    {
        return Socialite::driver('google')->redirect();


    }

    /**
     * Obtain the user information from GitHub.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function handleProviderCallback(Request $request)
    {
        \Log::Info("handleProviderCallback");
        $query = $request->query();
        \Log::Info($query);
        $user = Socialite::driver('google')->stateless()->user();
        \Log::Info($user);

        // $user->token;    
    }
```

Comment: provide the line where you use the `$user` var

Comment: replace `\Log::Info($user);` with `\Log::Info($user->id);` and test again !

Comment: sorry it reaches there it worked now thanks a lot

Comment: @SUNILBABU  `\Log::info($user)` is throwing that error ... `Log::info` takes a string for the first argument .. you are passing an object, that object can't be converted to a string

Comment: That's why i said _replace `\Log::Info($user);` with `\Log::Info($user->id);` and test again !_ :)

Comment: Thank every one you were correct

Answer (score 0):

```
\Log::Info($user);
```

This needs string not object. You are passing an object instead of a string.

Answer (score 0):

info(print_r($user,true));

show all the detail with laravel helper function